# Issues about using rpm -U to upgrade an installed package

Tags: installation, package, upgrade, rpm

After the first installing the package example.rpm using `rpm -Uvh ./example.rpm`. I deleted some config files of example by mistake. Then the second time, I use rpm -Uvh ./example.rpm. it said the package is already installed. so it is stilling missing the config files I deleted. 
How to change the command to let it install the config files?

Comment: actually, it is that I delete all the files that the example.rpm has installed. Then I use the command to install it again. And it says "the package has already been installed".

Comment: maybe it can be resolved by adding --force to the command or removing the installed package first and then use the command to install it again:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 --replacepkgs                    reinstall if the package is already present
```

According to

```
rpm --help
```